# getting error- "chartobject-1.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element." in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, fusioncharts

I'm using fusion charts where I'm showing 2 charts in html page using javascript. individually I'm able to show 2 charts but while I want to show 2 charts at a time , I'm getting error saying - "fusioncharts.js:71 Uncaught RuntimeException: #03091456 chartobject-1.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element." I'm getting error in the second javascript function at this line"
**}).render();**"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="FusionChartsXT/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script>
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            var csatscorechart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'angulargauge',
                renderat: 'chart-container',
                width: '400',
                height: '300',
                dataformat: 'json',
                datasource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "ph level in pond",
                        "subcaption": "current ph level",
                        "lowerlimit": "0",
                        "upperlimit": "14",
                        "showgaugeborder": "1",
                        "gaugebordercolor": "{dark-30}",
                        "gaugeborderthickness": "5",
                        "gaugeborderalpha": "14",
                        "showvalue": "1",
                        "valuebelowpivot": "1",
                        "theme": "fint"
                    },
                    "colorrange": {
                        "color": [
                            {
                                "minvalue": "0",
                                "maxvalue": "4",
                                "code": "#e44a00"
                            },
                            {
                                "minvalue": "5",
                                "maxvalue": "10",
                                "code": "#6baa01"
                            },
                            {
                                "minvalue": "10",
                                "maxvalue": "14",
                                "code": "#f8bd19"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "dials": {
                        "dial": [{
                            "value": "7"
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }).render();
        });

        //Tempreture sensor charts 
        FusionCharts.ready(function(){
            var fusionchartstemp = new FusionCharts({
                    type: 'thermometer',
                renderAt: 'chart-containertemp',
                id: 'myThm',
                width: '240',
                height: '310',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                        "chart": {
                                "caption": "Temperature Monitor",
                                "subcaption": " Central cold store",
                                "lowerLimit": "-10",
                                "upperLimit": "0",
                                "decimals": "1",
                                "numberSuffix": "°C",
                                "showhovereffect": "1",
                                "thmFillColor": "#008ee4",
                                "showGaugeBorder": "1",
                                "gaugeBorderColor": "#008ee4",
                                "gaugeBorderThickness": "2",
                                "gaugeBorderAlpha": "30",
                                "thmOriginX": "100",
                                "chartBottomMargin": "20",
                                "valueFontColor": "#000000",
                               "theme": "fint"
                            },
                            "value": "-6",
                            //All annotations are grouped under this element
                        "annotations": {
                                "showbelow": "0",
                                "groups": [{
                                        //Each group needs a unique ID
                                        "id": "indicator",
                                        "items": [
                                            //Showing Annotation
                                            {
                                        "id": "background",
                                        //Rectangle item
                                            "type": "rectangle",
                                            "alpha": "50",
                                            "fillColor": "#AABBCC",
                                            "x": "$gaugeEndX-40",
                                            "tox": "$gaugeEndX",
                                            "y": "$gaugeEndY+54",
                                            "toy": "$gaugeEndY+72"
                                        }
                                ]
                            }]

         },
     },
    "events": {
                    "initialized": function(evt, arg) {
                            evt.sender.dataUpdate = setInterval(function() {
                                    var value,
                                        prevTemp = evt.sender.getData(),
                                        mainTemp = (Math.random() * 10) * (-1),
                                        diff = Math.abs(prevTemp - mainTemp);

                                    diff = diff > 1 ? (Math.random() * 1) : diff;
                                    if (mainTemp > prevTemp) {
                                            value = prevTemp + diff;
                                        } else {
                                            value = prevTemp - diff;
                                        }

                                    evt.sender.feedData("&value=" + value);

                                }, 3000);
                            updateAnnotation = function(evtObj, argObj) {
                                    var code,
                                        chartObj = evtObj.sender,
                                        val = chartObj.getData(),
                                        annotations = chartObj.annotations;

                                    if (val >= -4.5) {
                                            code = "#00FF00";
                                        } else if (val < -4.5 && val > -6) {
                                                code = "#ff9900";
                                            } else {
                                                code = "#ff0000";
                                            }
                                    annotations.update("background", {
                                            "fillColor": code
                                    });
                            };
                    },
        'renderComplete': function(evt, arg) {
                        updateAnnotation(evt, arg);
                    },
        'realtimeUpdateComplete': function(evt, arg) {
                        updateAnnotation(evt, arg);
                    },
        'disposed': function(evt, arg) {
                        clearInterval(evt.sender.dataUpdate);
                    }
            }
        }
        );
            fusionchartstemp.render();
        });



    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div align="center">
        <h1>
            Pond Gaurd
        </h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <div id="chart-containertemp">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="height:333px"></div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are doing well.While creating the chart constructor you mentioned 'renderat' which should be 'renderAt' that's why it was throwing exception "fusioncharts.js:71 Uncaught RuntimeException: #03091456 chartobject-1.render() Error >> Unable to find the container DOM element.Please refer to the corrected code. It is working fine.
    Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script type="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
    <script>
        FusionCharts.ready(function () {
            var csatscorechart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'angulargauge',
                renderAt: 'chart-container',
                width: '400',
                height: '300',
                dataformat: 'json',
                datasource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "ph level in pond",
                        "subcaption": "current ph level",
                        "lowerlimit": "0",
                        "upperlimit": "14",
                        "showgaugeborder": "1",
                        "gaugebordercolor": "{dark-30}",
                        "gaugeborderthickness": "5",
                        "gaugeborderalpha": "14",
                        "showvalue": "1",
                        "valuebelowpivot": "1",
                        "theme": "fint"
                    },
                    "colorrange": {
                        "color": [
                            {
                                "minvalue": "0",
                                "maxvalue": "4",
                                "code": "#e44a00"
                            },
                            {
                                "minvalue": "5",
                                "maxvalue": "10",
                                "code": "#6baa01"
                            },
                            {
                                "minvalue": "10",
                                "maxvalue": "14",
                                "code": "#f8bd19"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "dials": {
                        "dial": [{
                            "value": "7"
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }).render();
        });

        //Tempreture sensor charts 
        FusionCharts.ready(function(){
            var fusionchartstemp = new FusionCharts({
                    type: 'thermometer',
                renderAt: 'chart-containertemp',
                id: 'myThm',
                width: '240',
                height: '310',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                        "chart": {
                                "caption": "Temperature Monitor",
                                "subcaption": " Central cold store",
                                "lowerLimit": "-10",
                                "upperLimit": "0",
                                "decimals": "1",
                                "numberSuffix": "°C",
                                "showhovereffect": "1",
                                "thmFillColor": "#008ee4",
                                "showGaugeBorder": "1",
                                "gaugeBorderColor": "#008ee4",
                                "gaugeBorderThickness": "2",
                                "gaugeBorderAlpha": "30",
                                "thmOriginX": "100",
                                "chartBottomMargin": "20",
                                "valueFontColor": "#000000",
                               "theme": "fint"
                            },
                            "value": "-6",
                            //All annotations are grouped under this element
                        "annotations": {
                                "showbelow": "0",
                                "groups": [{
                                        //Each group needs a unique ID
                                        "id": "indicator",
                                        "items": [
                                            //Showing Annotation
                                            {
                                        "id": "background",
                                        //Rectangle item
                                            "type": "rectangle",
                                            "alpha": "50",
                                            "fillColor": "#AABBCC",
                                            "x": "$gaugeEndX-40",
                                            "tox": "$gaugeEndX",
                                            "y": "$gaugeEndY+54",
                                            "toy": "$gaugeEndY+72"
                                        }
                                ]
                            }]

         },
     },
    "events": {
                    "initialized": function(evt, arg) {
                            evt.sender.dataUpdate = setInterval(function() {
                                    var value,
                                        prevTemp = evt.sender.getData(),
                                        mainTemp = (Math.random() * 10) * (-1),
                                        diff = Math.abs(prevTemp - mainTemp);

                                    diff = diff > 1 ? (Math.random() * 1) : diff;
                                    if (mainTemp > prevTemp) {
                                            value = prevTemp + diff;
                                        } else {
                                            value = prevTemp - diff;
                                        }

                                    evt.sender.feedData("&value=" + value);

                                }, 3000);
                            updateAnnotation = function(evtObj, argObj) {
                                    var code,
                                        chartObj = evtObj.sender,
                                        val = chartObj.getData(),
                                        annotations = chartObj.annotations;

                                    if (val >= -4.5) {
                                            code = "#00FF00";
                                        } else if (val < -4.5 && val > -6) {
                                                code = "#ff9900";
                                            } else {
                                                code = "#ff0000";
                                            }
                                    annotations.update("background", {
                                            "fillColor": code
                                    });
                            };
                    },
        'renderComplete': function(evt, arg) {
                        updateAnnotation(evt, arg);
                    },
        'realtimeUpdateComplete': function(evt, arg) {
                        updateAnnotation(evt, arg);
                    },
        'disposed': function(evt, arg) {
                        clearInterval(evt.sender.dataUpdate);
                    }
            }
        }
        );
            fusionchartstemp.render();
        });



    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div align="center">
        <h1>
            Pond Gaurd
        </h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>

                </td>

                <td>
                    <div id="chart-containertemp">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>

                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="height:333px"></div>


    </div>

</body>
</html
```